# syntax error in foreach loop in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, function

I am working on these two table batches.batches and courses.course_teacher  In course table i have courseid batch_id and trainer_id ...So now my requirement is i want to check if batch have courses than i have to check all courses must have at least one trainer for all courses.below i provide you my old function that only check batch has trainer...but i want to check in a batch all course must have trainer.if there is a trainer for all course 
than return 1 else 0...

course table

```
CREATE TABLE courses.course_teacher (
id SERIAL,
courseid INTEGER NOT NULL,
is_deleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT false,
trainer_id INTEGER[],
batch_id INTEGER,
qp_id INTEGER,
pedagogy_session TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
assignedby INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT course_teacher_pkey PRIMARY KEY(id),
CONSTRAINT course_teacher_fk FOREIGN KEY (courseid)
REFERENCES courses.courses(id)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE
) 
WITH (oids = false);

CREATE INDEX inx_courses_course_teacher_batch_id ON            courses.course_teacher
USING btree (batch_id);

CREATE INDEX inx_courses_course_teacher_course_id ON     courses.course_teacher
USING btree (courseid);

 CREATE INDEX inx_courses_course_teacher_trainer_id ON courses.course_teacher
 USING btree (trainer_id);
```

My old function.............

```
DECLARE
d_trainerids INTEGER[];
BEGIN
-- Below query for active trainers only..
select array_agg(ua.id) into d_trainerids   
    from batches.batches bb 
    LEFT JOIN center.center cc on bb.centre_id = cc.id
    LEFT JOIN programs.program_courses ppc on bb.program_id =      ppc.program_id
    LEFT JOIN courses.course_teacher cct on cct.courseid::text = ANY(ppc.course_ids)
    LEFT JOIN users.accounts ua on ua.id = ANY(cct.trainer_id)
    where bb.centre_id = i_centerid --and bb.end_date::date >= now()::date 
    and bb.is_deleted = FALSE and bb.is_active = TRUE and cct.trainer_id <> '{}' and ua.status = 1;

return query
select b.id, b.batch_name, b.batch_code, --count(ud.id)::INTEGER,

(select count(ud.id) from users.userdetail ud LEFT JOIN users.roles ur on ur.user_id = ud.userid
    where b.id = ANY(ud.batch_id))::INTEGER, --and ud.centre_id = i_centerid and 2 = ANY(ur.roles))::INTEGER,

(select center_name from center.center where id = i_centerid and is_active = true and is_deleted = false),

(select id from center.center where id = i_centerid and is_active = true and is_deleted = false), pp.name,

to_char(b.start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy'), pp.id, to_char(b.end_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
case        when b.status = '1' THEN 'Ongoing'::text
              when b.status = '2' THEN 'Closed'::text
              when b.status = '3' THEN 'Cancelled'::text
              when b.status = '4' then 'Open'::text
              when b.status = '5' then 'Closed & Billed'::text END,

case when b.actualregistration = null then '0'
     WHEN b.actualregistration::text = ' ' then '0' 
     else b.actualregistration::text end,
     --case for checking trainer in a batch
case when (d_trainerids @> (select array_unique(array_agg(ua.id))
        from courses.course_teacher cct 
        left join users.accounts ua on ua.id = ANY(cct.trainer_id) and ua.status <> 0
        where b.id = cct.batch_id and cct.trainer_id <> '{}' and ua.status <> 0)) = TRUE THEN 1::INTEGER ELSE 0::INTEGER END,

case when b.end_date::date >= now()::date then 'Open' else 'Close' END, 0

from batches.batches b
--LEFT join users.userdetail ud on b.id = ANY(ud.batch_id)
--LEFT JOIN users.roles ur on ur.user_id = ud.userid
LEFT JOIN programs.programs pp on b.program_id = pp.id
LEFT JOIN programs.program_courses ppc on pp.id = ppc.program_id
where b.centre_id = i_centerid and b.is_active = true and b.is_deleted = false ORDER by b.start_date DESC; --and b.end_date::date >= now()::date 
--GROUP by b.id, b.batch_name, b.batch_code, pp.name, b.start_date, pp.id, ppc.course_ids;
END;
```

This a older one case

```
 --case for checking trainer in a batch
case when (d_trainerids @> (select array_unique(array_agg(ua.id))
        from courses.course_teacher cct 
        left join users.accounts ua on ua.id = ANY(cct.trainer_id) and ua.status <> 0
        where b.id = cct.batch_id and cct.trainer_id <> '{}' and ua.status <> 0)) = TRUE THEN 1::INTEGER ELSE 0::INTEGER END,
```

Above code check the condition in a batch if i have a trainer in a batch then it will return me 1 else 0....but problem is that a batch can have multiple courses.so i want to change this case for checking trainer for every course....so i just put a foreach loop for checking condition

```
(foreach cctcourse in ARRAY cct.courseid loop 
            if cctcourse is not null THEN
            cct.trainer_id<>'{}' and ua.status <> 0
            end if;
            end loop;) )) = TRUE THEN 1::INTEGER ELSE 0::INTEGER END,
```

but after adding this i got a error syntax error, I replace this code with original

```
     case when (d_trainerids @> (select array_unique(array_agg(ua.id))
        from courses.course_teacher cct 
        left join users.accounts ua on ua.id = ANY(cct.trainer_id) and ua.status <> 0
        where   (foreach cctcourse in ARRAY cct.courseid loop 
                if cctcourse is not null THEN
                cct.trainer_id<>'{}' and ua.status <> 0
                end if;
                end loop;) )) = TRUE THEN 1::INTEGER ELSE 0::INTEGER END,
```

In the above code i am getting a error

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "cctcourse"
>   LINE 44:             where   (foreach cctcourse in ARRAY cct.courseid...

I am just taking all values from `cct.courseid` and stored in a variable `cctcourse` but when i want execute this it display me this error where am i wrong??how can i solve this....

Comment: You can't loop in a query. You can for example  loop over query results. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Please check again i edit my question i think now you can understand actual problem.....

Comment: Can i use foreach loop in where clause or not????

Comment: You can't `loop` or `if` in a query. It's not SQL syntax. Please show your table schema and sample data and explain what you are trying to do. We might provide a better solution using `plpgsql` function.

Comment: @Elad  I provide you table structure and my requirement please check and give me solution....

Comment: @Elad please check again

Comment: @sachinupadhya You have courses and teachers. What is a trainer then? As you say in the first paragraph course table has trainerId and courses table has multiple trainerId. Also both course and teacher have batchId. I did not get your structure.

Comment: @NuriTasdemir No,I have two table only  one is `Courses.course_Tearcher ` and other one is   `batches.batches` in Course_teacher i have column   `courseid,batcheid,trainerid` and in batches table i have `batchid and courseid and many more`